# How is prolog's expressiveness more restricted than First Order Logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

I gather than first order logic (FOL) is a mathematical creation. Prolog on the other hand is a logic programming language that closely resembles (implements?) FOL.

I am wondering in what way is Prolog's expressiveness, when interpreted in a non-executable manner (i.e. as logic statements), more limited if at all, than FOL? And if it is more limited, why where the limitations introduced.

Comment: Can you have rules like the first-order rules of demodulation and paramodulation in Prolog?  This source might have some relevance: http://www.ai.sri.com/~stickel/pttp.html

Answer (score 1):

Prolog includes *predicates* that also appear in *predicate logic*. The language you use writing a data base in Prolog is something like the language of FOL but a much weaker language because you can't use quantifiers. I am not an expert but maybe this answer is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Perhaps in Prolog quantifiers are implied/implicit. if I write person(X) :- man(X)
person(X) :- woman(X).

Then perhaps with person(X) is say there exists an X such that person(X) And the facts in the database are then the "domain" for X.  Not sure how for all looks like. Perhaps the set built in predicats that look for all facts.